# how to get AWS EC2 pricelist via PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

I try to get AWS Ec2 instance programmatically , so, I need a way to get the price list and quotes via AWS-SDK for PHP or any API endpoint for AWS

API version I used is v3

Comment: SO is for coding issues questions, not for API/libraries requests.

Comment: For API, so I need the api endpoint for getting the pricelist of instance, not code issue

Comment: I think you are missing my point. SO is for coding issues, not API requests.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Grant IAM Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-example-policies.html#example-policy-pe-api) to Use the AWS Price List Service API
2. Use the [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/API_Operations_AWS_Price_List_Service.html)

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/using-pelong.html